# How to scale a rigged character to a new height?

Tags: rigging, transforms

I made a rig and character model, linked him into a scene and found he was a bit too tall. He's about 6"6' and I want him to be a bit shorter but when I try to scale him down and apply the scale the model doesn't scale correctly with the rig. Is there an easy way to make him shorter without completely redoing the weights and everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scale the *armature* to the right height and then apply the scale.  The model should scale to match.

Then select the model and apply scale to it.

Comment: Thank you! It almost didn't work but I had to be in rest pose for it to work correctly.

Comment: @Elven_Randomness  Since you're apparently a new user to Blender StackExchange, you might want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and perhaps accept my answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad you were able to figure out the extra step.

Comment: i tried that with my model + armature (downloaded from mixamo) and then the animation was totally !/"§!&/( up :(

Comment: @Chris What I suggested works on a rig+model that are fairly fresh and have no other modifiers or animations. If you post a question with a Mixamo example, I'll see what else it requires.

Comment: @MartyFouts : it’s ok. I already asked that and Josh had an answer for me which worked.

Comment: @Chris cool.  Josh is definitely a rigging and animation god.