# How to scale a rigged object just in z direction?

Tags: rigging

Bloody rigger beginner here:

So i successfully rigged my little cube here:

[image]

Now i wanted to have exactly the same just with half z height of that.

So i saw another answer here on SE and the answer said: scale down the root bone.

So i scaled down my root bone on z by 2 (so the scale z value in pose mode is 0.5)

result:

[image]

Nope, that's not what i wanted :(

I think you pro rigger know how i wanted that, right?

What did i make wrong?

[image]

Comment: Does [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/250437/42221) work for you? (Scale the rig not the bone)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scale a rigged character to a new height?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250435/how-to-scale-a-rigged-character-to-a-new-height)

Comment: unfortunately...no. i tried that. Didn't work :(

Comment: post the rig and I'll take a look

Comment: posted it.......

Comment: Two armatures and bone parenting instead of vertex parenting is just a bit much for me.  I made it work by scaling both armatures and _not_ applying scale, but I think that will give you problems later.

Comment: @MartyFouts: For me personally i think direct parenting of mesh to bone is much easier than with vertex weights ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133417/discussion-between-marty-fouts-and-chris).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the procedure for what (I think) you wanted:

Select bottom face of the mesh and use Shift S to set there the 3D cursor.
Set 3D cursor as pivot point.
In pose mode scale Upper and Lower bones in Z by 0.5.
Select top mesh and use Alt P clear parent (Keep tramsform).
Same for bottom mesh.
Apply Scale for top and bottom mesh.
Select Armature in pose mode and use Ctrl A Apply pose as rest pose.
Bone parent the meshes to the relative bones.

[image: scaled results]

Comment: i got it working, thank you very much. Is it possible, that i had to apply visual transform to pose? because if i chose pose as rest pose the cubes got big again...

Comment: You have to do it after clearing parentship (and keep transform).